# Using powershell to move/make folders/subfolders based on filename

Tags: powershell

I don't really have much experience in powershell but I have files that I need to organize. The files are all pdf and will have a format similar to "Dept123_Name_year.pdf".

I want to move the documents into a folder based on "Dept123" and a sub folder "Name". If the folder is yet to exist I would like it to create the folder/subfolder.

To make it easier I was thinking of using creating an "Organize" folder on the desktop and running the program on that. If you think it'd be easier some other way, let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And the question is? What have you tried so far?

Comment: `Get-Help`, `Get-Command`, `Get-Member`. Use these to learn your way around.  The `Get-Alias` cmdlet will help you determine the PS equiv. to the CMD commands you know. So, try `Get-Alias dir` and `Get-Alias cd`.  `dir` is an alias for `Get-ChildItem`, so you use `Get-Help GetChildItem` to read about how to use it. Search the web for Powershell tutorials. Manipulating files are tasks that are commonly used to illustrate scripting concepts. For best results, use this forum for help with code you've written that generates errors or other unexpected results.  (Show code and errors)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to match the different components of the filenames, then generate a directory structure based on that. The `-Force` parameter of `mkdir` lets you ignore whether or not the directory already exists:

```
$list = ls
for ($i=0; $i -le $list.Length; $i++) {
    if ($list[$i].Name -match '([A-Za-z0-9]+)_([A-Za-z]+)_.*\.pdf') {
        $path = Join-Path $matches[1] $matches[2]
        mkdir -Force -Path $path
        cp $list[$i] "$path\."
    }
}
```

The regular expression part is in the quotes; you might need to modify it to suit your specific needs. Note that the sections in round brackets correspond to the different parts of the name being extracted; these parts are loaded, in order, into the `$matches` variable, which is generated automatically. E.g. `'([A-Za-z0-9]+)\.txt'` will match any text file with only letters or numbers in the name, and will stick the actual name - minus the extension - into `$matches[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Using regex and full-form Powershell:

```
# using ?<name> within a () block in regex causes powershell to 'name' the property 
# with the given name within the automatic variable, $matches, object.
$Pattern = "(?<Dept>.*)_(?<Name>.*)_(?<Year>.*)\.pdf"

# Get a list of all items in the current location.  The location should be set using
# set-location, or specified to the command by adding -Path $location
$list = Get-ChildItem

# Foreach-Object loop based on the list of files
foreach ($file in $list) {
    # send $true/$false results from -matches operation to $null
    $File.Name -matches $Pattern 2> $Null

    # build destination path from the results of the regex match operation above
    $Destination = Join-Path $matches.Dept $matches.Name

    # Create the destination if it does not exist
    if (!(Test-Path $Destination) ) { 
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $destination 
    }

    # Copy the file, keeping only the year part of the name
    Copy-Item $file "$destination\$($matches.year)"+".pdf"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I like the idea with the last part, but there are a few times in which these files need to be sent or copied and it would make little sense to get rid of the first half of the name. In any case your code helped me understand powershell a bit better. I changed the last line to      `Move-Item $file "$Destination\$($file.Name)"`     . However if I happen to use the code more than once (after the files have been initially categorized) it starts moving all other folders into another. I've had no luck figuring it out.